# How to use QTest QBENCHMARK macros result as a parameter in a unit test

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, macros, qtestlib

I am writing some unit tests using QTest in Qt. I also encountered the QBENCHMARK macro, which  benchmarks the code it encapsulates.

I am running my unit tests and benchmarks some of the code. The QBENCHMARK reports how long it took to execute some method and that is fine. I want to use the execution time in a unit test with for example QVERIFY2(). How can I do this?

EDIT:

What I am currently doing is:

```
void UnitTest::benchmark()
{
    QString str1 = QLatin1String("This is a test string");
    QString str2 = QLatin1String("This is a test string");

    QCOMPARE(str1.localeAwareCompare(str2), 0);

    QBENCHMARK {
        str1.localeAwareCompare(str2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean you would like to compare the execution time with a value or are you looking for [something like this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtest.html#setBenchmarkResult)?

Comment: I'll try that. It seems to do what I want and more :)

Comment: I want to compare the execution time with a value =)

Comment: and what exactly is wrong about QElapsedTimer as the simplest solution mentioned at the end of the answer?

Comment: @FinalContest: It does work, but it does not average automatically like the QBENCHMARK do. It is a good solution, but maybe not the best.

Comment: what do you mean by "does not average"?

Comment: The QBENCHMARK automatically averages n number of executions of what it encapsulates for more accurate result. The number to averages it determined by Qt.

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation:

> [void QTest::setBenchmarkResult(qreal result, QBenchmarkMetric metric)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtest.html#setBenchmarkResult)
>
> Sets the benchmark result for this test function to result.
>
> Use this function if you want to report benchmark results without using the QBENCHMARK macro. Use metric to specify how Qt Test should interpret the results.
>
> The context for the result will be the test function name and any data tag from the _data function. This function can only be called once in each test function, subsequent calls will replace the earlier reported results.
>
> Note that the -iterations command line argument has no effect on test functions without the QBENCHMARK macro.

You could also of course just use [an elapsed timer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html) for such a thing.

Comment: I updated the question with the code I am currently running. I don't quite understand how I can get it to work similar with setBenchmarkResult? It says its context is the test function and eventually the test function _data, but I tried with the WallTimeNano and its just 0.00000000. The macro averages the run time over many measurements, not sure if this one does? I am trying to write equally functional code as the one I have in my question.

Comment: @Phataas: you have not replied to my initial comment. It is unclear what you are trying to achieve.